# Change spinner status with class Glade Gtk+ python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, glade

I am starting to learn python3 using gtk+ to create ui.

So i like to make spinner start work in my ui when button is clicked but nothing happens when button was clicked

if i follow GTK+ tutorial the spinner work fine.  But i like to use class in my code I like the sugestion here (http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html#example) to make some class to invoke actions in connect_signals

someone can help me ?

my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

try:
    from gi.repository import Gtk
except ImportError:
    print >> sys.stderr, 'ERRO: requer a lib python3-gi'
    sys.exit(1)

require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

class application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("stack.glade")
        self.builder.connect_signals(actions())
        self.spinner = self.builder.get_object("spinner1")

    def spinner_start(self):
        self.spinner.start()

class actions:

    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)

    def onButtonClick(self, widget, button="button1"):
        application().spinner_start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = application()
    window = main.builder.get_object("window1")
    window.show()
    Gtk.main()
```

my glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="onButtonClick" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSpinner" id="spinner1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: This is a guess: does `application().spinner_start()` create a new instance of `application`?

Comment: should not create.

Comment: Are you sure? Running a simple test in the interactive Python shell shows me otherwise... Try adding a `print("init")` to your `application` class's `__init__` and see if that shows up more than once.